# Capturing Tabbed Focus/Blur properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So for accessibility purposes I am trying to captured tabbed `focus` and `blur` events to capture tab order within a modal.

For some reason I am running into some odd browser behavior.

Inside my component I have the following code:

```
// On Init
ngOnInit (){

    // Get all of the buttons and anchors in the modal
    var buttons = this.modal.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("button, a");

    // Get the number of buttons
    var numButtons = buttons.length;

    // Get the last button
    var lastButton = buttons[numButtons - 1];

    // When the last button loses focus
    lastButton.addEventListener("blur", (e: any) => {

        // Prevent Default
        e.preventDefault();

        // Focus on the modals close button
        this.focusCloseButton();
    })
}
```

And TECHNICALLY this works perfectly. If I log out the active element after the call to `this.focusCloseButton`, I indeed get a reference to the close button.

HOWEVER, the tab actually moves to the browser itself into whatever the first element is. For Chrome this is the "View site information" button to the left of the URL bar. In Firefox this is the first tab in the list of tabs.

How can I capture this properly so that the browser is not hijacking the tab press?

Comment: Do you know what the last button is? If so, does applying `(blur)="focusCloseButton()"` to it in the template resolve the issue?

I'd be interested in a Plunker replicating the issue you're having.

Could we also see your focusCloseButton implementation?

Comment: Added plunk to show functionality and expose code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `blur` event happens too late to be captured before the browser takes over.

Instead I used keybinding to detect when the tab-key was pressed and did the capturing from there.

```
// The OnInit function handles capturing tab order
ngOnInit (){

    // All of the buttons and links in the modal
    var buttons = this.modal.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("button, a");

    // The first button or link in the modal
    var firstButton = buttons[0];

    // The last button or link in the modal
    var lastButton = buttons[buttons.length - 1];

    // Listen for keydown events on the modal
    this.modal.nativeElement.addEventListener("keydown", (e: any)=> {

        // If the key pressed was the tab button
        if ( e.keyCode === 9 && !e.shiftKey ) {

            // If the currently active element is the last button
            if (document.activeElement == lastButton){

                // Prevent default action
                e.preventDefault();

                // Put focus on the close button
                this.focusCloseButton();
            }
        } else if ( e.keyCode === 9 && e.shiftKey === true ){

            // If the key pressed was shift+tab
            // And the currently active button is the close button
            if ( document.activeElement == firstButton ){

                // Prevent Default
                e.preventDefault();

                // Focus the last button
                lastButton.focus();
            }
        }
    })
}
```

for those wondering about what this.focusCloseButton does:

```
// Puts focus on the close button
focusCloseButton: Function = function(){
    this.closeButton.nativeElement.focus();
};
```

The reference to closeButton is created by ViewChild:

```
// Reference to the close button
@ViewChild("closeButton") closeButton: ElementRef;
```

Which ties into the dom with the marked element:

```
<button #closeButton></button>
```